# How can we rewrite the response of APIs in OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

We have application that is running inside a pod, to access that I have created the service and exposed it.
The route-url is for example : example-city.apps.cluster.com to access my application  say server
There is any Rest-API calls where, I get json data in which one the field is URL which is mapped to pod-name:80 through my application.

There is client application which get's connected to these server using route-URL, once it is connected there are Rest-API calls, that give me back the json data. As, in json data I don't have route-url but pod-name:80, my application does get connected to it.

So, what I am looking for is, my json data when it does in response, I need to change that pod-name:80 to route-url, in short I want to replace my pod-name with route-url ie. I want to rewrite-response.

Please suggest, how can we do these and what all changes are required in service or route yaml files.

Comment: "As, in json data I don't have route-url but pod-name:80". How do you retrieve this? some code on your side? what code? from an HTTP header? If you were not on OpenShift, how would you retrieve the correct value?

Comment: The correct value was retrieved by API calls, normally it would be the machine name with port number, as our DNS knows the machine name, it would be accessible directly. As, we have moved to OpenShift, we are facing these issue.

Comment: "The correct value was retrieved by API calls" what API call? to OpenShift? to where? that does what to retrieve the external address?

Comment: It is thorough our application, it returns json data contaning the hostname as machine name, and in case of pod it is pod's name. As, it is pod name, it cannot be accessible from outside.

Comment: so this logic is not the correct one to retrieve your external URL in a containerized world. . maybe you should use standard http headers for this (x-forwarded-for etc..) and update your logic to retrieve those headers with the correct external url from the REST request. of course the intermediates "routers/load balancers" etc must be configured to update those headers along the path. Check the OpenShift doc to configure HAProxy (the ingress controller of OCP) to append the url to the header x-forwarded-for header (it does it by default..)

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/networking/ingress-operator.html#nw-ingress-controller-configuration-parameters_configuring-ingress

Answer (score 0):

What about deploying an additional reverse proxy like nginx for the purpose of rewriting?

Firstly, you need to deploy Nginx using a ConfigMap.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.22
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http-web
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: nginx-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
     app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: nginx
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: http-web

---
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  host: awsome-app.example.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: nginx
```

Then, you can do rewriting in ConfigMap

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name awsome-app.example.com

      # your rewriting rules here
      # for example
      location / {
         sub_filter '<your-pod-name>:80' '<your-desired-route-url>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain it more. It is possible to do, have you tried it.

Comment: I've never faced the problem you described. But usually, I deploy a Nginx as an API gateway for my system.

Comment: I have updated the description in my answer.

Comment: Should, I have a separate deployment of my application say it listens on port 9080. 
Will these be separate service that need to be created for it. 
How will my nginx now about my application?

Comment: In the ConfigMap, you define `proxy_pass` to your service. For example, `proxy_pass http://<your-service-name-to-your-app>:9080;`